# How to add index and units reference in a dataframe with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df` which contains a lot of columns unnecessary, and also a dictionary called `dict` where it's included the desired columns as key, and the units as item inside each key:
    `dict = {'time': 'date', 'place': 'London'}`

I need a new dataframe (`final_df`) with only the columns included as key in my `dict`, and include as first row (index) the key of the `dict`, and as second row the item inside each key of the `dict` (units of the index).

**Current `df` example**

[image]

**Desired `final_df` dataframe**

[image]

I tried with:

```
    dict = {'time': 'date', 'place': 'London'}
    keys = []
    for key in dict:
        for col in df.columns:
            if col == key:
                keys.append(col)
    final_df = df[keys]
```

It works but I don't know how to include the units in the second row. 
How can I also add it in my `final_df`?
Any other suggestion of how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of what you want:

Generating a testing example (*you should always post a [testable fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ) for quicker+better answers*):

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,4)),columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)
```

---

```
    A   B   C   D
0  44  47  64  67
1  67   9  83  21
2  36  87  70  88
3  88  12  58  65
4  39  87  46  88
```

Solution:

1. Create a dataframe by filtering only the columns present in the
   dictionary keys.
2. [Create a Multiindex from keys and values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) from the 
   dictionary and assign to the dataframe and assign back to the columns.

---

```
d= {'A': 'Col1', 'D': 'Col2'} #reference dictionary
final = df.loc[:,d.keys()]
final.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((d.keys(),d.values()))
print(final)
```

---

```
     A    D
  Col1 Col2
0   44   67
1   67   21
2   36   88
3   88   65
4   39   88
```

Note: Please do not name a dictionary as `dict` since it will override default dictionary functionalities.

Comment: And do you know how to export it as csv with MultiIndex? `final.to_csv(output_path + '/test.csv')` doesn't work and I think I need `index_label` but I don't know how to setup it.

Comment: @Sergio just tried and it works for me (do you need `index=False` ?)... Do you get any error?

Comment: Yes... I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`. Probably it's because my dictionary contains more items than my dataframe.

Comment: @Sergio this means you are trying to export the multiindex columns to csv instead of the dataframe.  seems like naing the variables arent ryt n your case, i just tried `final.to_csv(..)` and it works